# É possível validar id de um get sem javascript?

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de validar o id do GET sem javascript, apenas com php. Estou com muita dificuldade.

```
<a id="exemplo-'.$resultado['id'].' " href="pagina.php"> 

<?php    
/*com javascript*/

 $id = explode('-',$_POST['exemplo']); 
 $ext = end($id);

 /*com O php se valida id assim?*/ 

 $id = explode('-',$_GET['exemplo']);
 $ext = end($id); 

?>
```

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite. Se vier por GET verifique primeiro se a chave existe com `isset()` depois veja se o valor informado é um número válido, pode ser feito com um cast ou `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: O problema é que vc não consegue recuperar o `id` do link?

Comment: sim @rray , eu estava acompanhando um tutorial, e nesse tutorial o get era validado com js .attr('post') , mas eu quero validar com o php

Comment: Boa tarde, não vejo nenhum javascript aonde escreveu `/*com javascript*/`, poderia ser mais claro? O que exatamente javascript tem haver com isto?

Comment: porque no javascript tem o .attr('post') que valida um $_post se eu fosse colocar o js ficaria muito extenso @Guilherme Nascimento

Comment: Desculpe, mas isto não está especificado no corpo da pergunta amigo é altamente recomendável que leia este link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento nao lerei , estou no stack desde 2014 conheço as regras , o array respondeu a minha duvida, ok obrigado

Comment: Tudo bem, não precisa ler, a sua pergunta não apresenta nada sobre o uso do `attr()` dentro do corpo, isto torna muito difícil ajudar, fico feliz que o @rray lhe ajudou e ao mesmo tempo triste que infelizmente você não aceite bem criticas construtivas (**não** estou falando do link). Eu mesmo estou aqui desde 2014 e frequento todos os dias e ainda cometo alguns enganos, é normal.

Comment: acontece que eu fiz a pergunta pelo cel @Guilherme Nascimento , sou iniciante no phpoo , achei legal a sua iniciativa entendo mencionei javascript na pergunta sem estar no código eu vi um tutorial que valida um get com js , eu queria fazer ao contrario

Comment: Amigo, independente de ser php, java, c#, javascript, mysql, html ou qualquer coisa o problema é com a pergunta feita, faltou detalhes, apenas isto, apenas estou lhe orientando, pra que nas próximas perguntas você consiga transmitir melhor o problema e com detalhes, facilitando o lado de quem vai responder, hoje felizmente houve um usuário (o @rray) com boa vontade e teve interesse em responder, mas nem sempre é assim quando a pergunta não tem detalhes ou está um pouco confusa. Espero que não leve a mal. Até mais.

Answer (score 3):

Ao enviar requesições por GET, os paramentros e os valores devem ser enviados pela url, não serve de nada o atributo `id` das tags do html.

Modifique seu link para:

```
<a href="pagina.php?id=<?php echo $resultado['id'];?>">EDITAR</a>
```

Pode fazer um teste preliminar para saber se o nome do indíce e o valor passado é bastante útil, assim:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_GET); //ou $_POST em outras ocasiões
```

Validação do id:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id'])){
   echo 'válido';
}else{
   echo 'inválido';
}
```

Comment: vc lembra do problema que eu estava com unlink? ele apaga as img do BD e da pasta o problema é que apaga todas as img , por isso eu fiz essa pergunta , eu queria renomear o link da imagem ex: <a id="exemplo-'.$resultado['id'].' " href="pagina.php"> <img src="upload/foto.jpg"></a>

Comment: Se for fazer por php, precisa passar o id pela url, passe o mouse em cima do link, vai ver que sempre o `?id=`

Comment: apareceu o id da foto id=1 vou criar uma variavel pra validar a foto , estou com medo do usuario apagar a foto de outro ex: site.php?fotoid=1&acao=deletephoto=1